# How to access related object (many to many)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name='follower')
```

I try to use {{userProfile.restaurant_set.all}} to get all restaurant the user following but it returns all restaurant the user owns.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
userProfile.follower.all()
```